# Is there a name for function where the order of its arguments doesn't change its output?

Tags: functions

Is there a name for a function $f$ such that $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = y$ for all permutations of $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$? Or a better notation to express this property?

If I called it a commutative function would you understand it?

Comment: Let $f$ and $g$ be functions from a set $X$ to itself. We say that $f$ and $g$ commute if $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ for all $x\in X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression that you're after is “symmetric function”.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen functions satisfying $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ called *symmetric*. If you denote $f(x,y)$ using some binary operator, i.e. $f(x,y) = x \circ y$ with predefined meaning, we could say that $\circ$ (or $f$) is a symmetric relation.